# RESTful PUT request converted to GET for 'open in new window'

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, browser, restful-url

SUMMARY: My PUT request is converted to GET when opened in a new tab or window.

DETAILS:
I have a Spring server that works properly if the user confines it to a single window. But if the user starts using "right click, open in new window" the PUT requests fail.

I've a RESTFUL server written with Spring MVC.  For example, an editing page is fetched with a link that calls GET mysite.com/myapp/admin/user/4.  When the changes are saved a button is mapped to submit the form to PUT mysite.com/myapp/admin/user/4.  Works fine.

(Actually, my stack does have HiddenHttpMethodFilter installed to handle the PUT requests.)

When my user clicks on a link to select an organization the link calls PUT mysite.com/myapp/admin/org/choose/7.  I use PUT because the server sets that org as default for the current user.

HOWEVER, suppose the user performs (right-click, Open link in new tab) on the browser.  Now the user gets:

HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported

- type Status report
- message Request method 'GET' not supported
- description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

The error is expected for a GET, but I originally sent out a PUT.

My question?  What is going on that the PUT is converted to GET for a window.open()?

Comment: That's because all the URLs you hit from a browser URL bar are by default generated as GET requests.

Comment: You imply that using window.open(), or using the browser's menu to do this, means that this particular request is always GET in that new window.  Can you give me a tutorial link for that?  I search for "browser url get" and get millions of unrelated search results.